# Pytest dynamic fixture scope - how to set and will the fixture scope apply to all tests?

Tags: pytest

I am trying to use pytest fixtures dynamic scoping.
The docs state that the scope will be determined during fixture definition; does it mean that once the scope is dynamically set in pytest run , this scope will apply to all tests using the fixture?
Is it possible to affect the scope during the test run (i.e using markers)?
If not, how can I change the config (without using a command line arg) to change the scope?

I tried to add a marker and use its value as a scope in pytest_generate_tests, however fixture definition runs prior to pytest_generate_tests.

```
def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    fixture_scope = metafunc.definition.get_closest_marker('scope').args
    if fixture_scope is not None:
        metafunc.config.addinivalue_line('markers', f'scope:{fixture_scope[0]}')


def determine_scope(fixture_name, config):
    scope = [i for i in config.getini('markers') if 'scope' in i][0]
    if scope:
        return scope.split(':')[-1]
    return "function"


@pytest.fixture(scope=determine_scope)
def some_fixture():
```

Comment: Maybe you should include in your question why you want to do that so that somebody can suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I would like to avoid duplication of code; I have some code that is needed in function level for some tests and in module level for other tests. I would like to re-use the same fixture for the 2 use-cases

Comment: Just thinking: you could put this code to be reused in a function `foo` and then define two fixtures: one with function scope and other with module scope which actually just call this function `foo` and then decorate the tests with fixtures as appropriate.

Comment: This is what I have done as a workaround; however creation of 2 exact fixtures with only a different scope, especially if you need to do it with multiple fixtures, is not really readable.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest using env var as scope. And change the env var if you want to change the scope. Scope change will only take effect once fixture's current scope ends.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope=os.environ.get("fixture_scope","function"))
def fixture_name():
    pass

def test_change_fixture():
    os.environ["fixture_scope"] = "class"
```

I have not tested this code. But I have found use of env var very useful in passing variables between different stages of pytest run. You can also use dynamic config file or something similar.

An ugly way to achieve that is to have 4 copies of same fixture and get the relevant fixture as needed.

```
def fixture_code():
    pass

@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def module_fixture():
    fixture_code()

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def session_fixture():
    fixture_code()

# similar fixtures for other scopes

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def fixture_provider(request, module_fixture, session_fixture, .....):
    if request.param['scope'] == "module":
       return module_fixture
    elif request.param['scope'] == "session":
       return session_fixture
    .
    .
    .

@pytest.mark.parametrize("scope",[os.environ.get("fixture_scope")], indirect=True)
def test_abc(fixture_provider):
   #use fixture provider.
```

You can set env var with code to get relevant fixture.

Comment: This does  not work for fixtures. I tried to set the env var before the test, but i think that the scope is determined only once, at the beginning of a test run.

Comment: Can you provide code you are using to check the correctness of solution? It can help me come up with something better.